# TypeError: data type '>' not understood using dtype from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

first I saw similar questions but nothing helped me.
I'm trying to sort list of tuples, and convert the data types inside the tuple,
convert it according to a list of tuples I get.
for example, if I have a list of tuple, every tuple is built like

```
(ID,Grade,Height)

A = [(123,23,67),(234,67,45)]
```

and I have a list of type like that:

`[(ID,int),(grade,'s15'),(height,float)]`

now I read that `'s15'` is a dtype from bumpy, but I can't seem to use it.
I tried to copy from the docs:

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype(('>14'))
```

but all I get is this error:

```
dt = np.dtype(('>14'))
TypeError: data type '>' not understood
```

the docs I copied from:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

and is there a generic converter I can use to convert to any type I'm given?

Comment: Where did you find `"s15"` and `">14"` (I don't see them on the linked page)? Note that `s` is not listed here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface, and that `>` only indicates the byte order, not the type.

Comment: Well, you didn;t copy it, because it's `'>i4'`, not `'>14'` in the docs. Check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs s15 is the type I got from the teacher, and about >14, apparently its '>i4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you maybe overlooked the documentation you are referring.
You used

```
dt = np.dtype(('>14'))
```

which is >14 (fourteen)...

But in fact the documentation clearly mentions

```
dt = np.dtype('>i4')
```

which is i4 not 1 (one)

Also based on the docs `>` or `<` specifies upper/lower bound for each dtype, for example `>i` would be big endian integer (see [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness))

And the number after that would indicate number of bytes given to the dtype (see [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing:%7E:text=data%20(void)-,Example,np.dtype(%27U25%27)%20%20%23%2025%2Dcharacter%20string,-Note%20on%20string))

Finally the `S` indicates `Zero terminated bytes`

Based on your description, your teacher wants `Upper endian ~128 bit Zero terminated bytes`

Furthermore,

```
dt = np.dtype(('>S15'))
```

works fine.

I hope this fixes your issue

Comment: yes I saw that now, but it still doesn't work with 's15' which is a type I got from the teacher, it is in the assignment

Comment: Updated the answer I think it will solve your issue now